# OCaml expression type issue

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml, currying

I am trying to make an OCaml function that addsthe number of 'a's in a string to a given argument.

```
let rec count_l_in_word (initial : int) (word : string) : int=
    if String.length word = 0 then initial else
    if word.[0] = 'a' then 
        count_l_in_word initial+1 (Str.string_after word 1)
    else count_l_in_word initial (Str.string_after word 1)
```

I get an error on line 4 saying 'This expression has type string -> int but is here used with type int'. I am not sure why it expects the expression 'count_l_in_word initial+1' to be an int. It should really expect the whole line 'count_l_in_word initial+1 (Str.string_after word 1)' to be an int.

Can anyone help with this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
count_l_in_word initial+1 (Str.string_after word 1)
```

is parsed as

```
(count_l_in_word initial) + (1 ((Str.string_after word) 1))
```

so you need to add some parens:

```
count_l_in_word (initial + 1) (Str.string_after word 1)
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess I have to be careful with with precedence. I got it working though

Comment: The rule, IIRC, is that function application has higher precedence than any operator. This is quite common in FP languages.

Comment: wouldn't it be parsed as `(count_l_in_word initial) + (1 ((Str.string_after word) 1))`?

Comment: @newacct: you're right. It hadn't crossed my mind that the parser would produce a function application with `1` as the function :)